# PHP--Error HTTP 500 -- when i try to connect to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

when i try to connect to the database i get error http 500 an i tried it on a local database it works fine when i uploaded it online nothing works

if i change my localhost
i get on of three errors

1-http 500

2-connection failed access denied for user

3-connection failed cant locate mysql host

**if anyone can help**

**thank you**

```
<?php
$Server = "localhost";
 $Username = "username";
 $PW = "password";
 $DB = "database";
$u=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Username');
$p=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Password');
$con = mysqli_connect($Server, $Username, $PW, $DB);

 if($con == false) {
     die("Error: " . mysqli_error_connect());
 }  

$st=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? ");
$st->bind_param('s', $u);
$st->execute();
$rs=$st->get_result();
if ($rs->num_rows > 0) {
while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) 
    {


     if ($u===$row["username"]&&$p===$row["password"])
    {
        echo "hi";



    }
        else 
            {
                 echo "Wrong username or password";

            }
    }     



} else {
    echo "wrong username or password";
}



 mysqli_close($connection);
 ?>
```

Comment: *1 - HTTP 500*: there is an error in your php. *2 - connection failed access denied for user*: check if the user/password exists for mysql. And you may have a look at the error logs.

Comment: It's clear: wrong username ond/or password.

Comment: Thank you for your help   ,,,I tried my code on a local database it works fine there is no problems in it 2- I checked the username and password they exist and correct 3- I can't find the error log